# Send email to address alternate from "To:"

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am implementing a sort of dynamic mailing-list system in Rails. I am looking to basically send an email and have the recipient receive it in this form:

```
From: person@whosentthis.com
To: mailing-list@mysite.com

<body>
```

Basically, the challenge is how do I send an email to an address while defining a different `To:` header so that they can easily reply to the mailing list or just the original sender?

Comment: The key to this is the difference between envelope headers and message headers. BCC is implemented by copying the recipient list to the envelope, then removing the BCC header. Basically, by taking control of the envelope headers, you can put anything you like in the To:, Cc:, and From: headers. I'm not a Ruby person so I don't feel qualified to post an answer, but hopefully this should at least get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mail vs. Envelope

In emails as in physical mails (paper sheet in paper envelope), the recipient on the envelope may differ from the recipient on the letter sheet itself.

As the mailman would only consider the envelope's recipient, so do mail servers.

That means, one actually can tell the smtp service to send and email to a recipient different than the one listed in the `To:` field of the emails header.

#### Trying This Out Manually

You can try this out, manually, for example, by using the `sendmail` command of postfix.

```
# bash
sendmail really_send_to_this_address@example.com < mail.txt
```

where

```
# mail.txt
From: foo@example.com
To: this_will_be_seen_in_the_to_field_in_email_clients@example.com
Subject: Testmail

This is a test mail.
```

This will deliver the email to `really_send_to_this_address@example.com`, not to `this_will_be_seen_in_the_to_field_in_email_clients@example.com`, but the latter will be shown in the recipient field of the mail client.

### Specifying the Envelope_to Field in Rails

The `ActionMailer::Base` internally uses the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). Currently, Apr 2013, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/mikel/mail/pull/477), allowing to specify the `envelope_to` field on a message before delivery.

Until this is pulled, you can specify the fork in the `Gemfile`.

```
# Gemfile 
# ...
gem 'mail', git: 'git://github.com/jeremy/mail.git'
```

You need to run `bundle update mail` after that, and, depending on your current rails version, maybe also `bundle update rails` in order to resolve some dependency issues.

After that, you can set the envelope recipient of a mail message like this:

```
# rails
message # => <Mail::Message ...>
message.to = [ "this_will_be_seen_in_the_to_field_in_email_clients@example.com" ]
message.smtp_envelope_to = [ "really_send_to_this_address@example.com" ]
message.from = ...
message.subject = ...
message.body = ...
message.deliver
```

### Documentation

- https://github.com/mikel/mail/pull/477
- http://rubydoc.info/github/jeremy/mail/master/Mail/Message#smtp_envelope_to%3D-instance_method
- https://github.com/mikel/mail

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the BCC header for this? Put `person@whoshouldreceivethis.com` into BCC and `mailing-list@mysite.com` into TO.

Clearification:

There is no technical solution for this. The email headers do what they do, you can't influence them in that once the email is on the way.

I am sure, though, you can find a combined use of TO, CC, BCC and REPLY-TO that gives you what you want.

Comment: You might want to check out the difference between CC and BCC on the one hand, and the use of REPLY-TO on the other hand, too. You should be able to find a combined use of these which suits your needs.

Comment: Doing that would cause an endless loop because it will just keep sending emails to itself (the mailing list).

Comment: Then put a no-reply address into the to and add mailing-list into the reply-to or something like that.

Comment: Yea, I had to re-write a bit of the SMTP delivery method of the mail gem. It's here if you want it: https://github.com/carlosdp/mail

Comment: You should have mentioned your project in you question. Your solution is all the stuff related to EnvelopeRecipient?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know about the difference between regular and envelope headers when I wrote the question.

Comment: Me neither :-) Reading RFCs helps!